# Can you change the view in Google Earth API from "Earth" to "Map" like in Google Maps?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I am developing a web page which uses the Google Earth plugin. I would like to display the map like in the first image with the "Earth" and "Satellite/Map" view options like you can in Google Maps, or at least be able to just show the map in "Satellite/Map" view:

[image]

Currently this is what the view looks like:

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Google Maps V3 to switch between Google Maps and the Google Earth Plug-in.

The [google-maps-utility-library-v3](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/) can be used to [make this easier](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/docs/reference.html).

You can see a [working example here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/examples/earth.html).

Alternatively you can simulate a reasonable map view buy just turning of the terrain and photo imagery and turning on the borders and roads layers in the Earth Plug-in. If you then lock this view to 'plan' it works well.

Comment: thanks for the response. Is it true that you can only turn off the photo imagery when using the Enterprise version?

Comment: Yes, although doing everything except that (i.e. turning of the terrain and turning on the borders and roads layers) will still give you a 'map like' view. Hope that helps.