# Integrate Google Maps Api V3 & Google Earth Api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I already have my map ready & loaded on website using GM API v3. Is there a way to integrate Google Earth Api without reprogramming the whole application??

- what I want for my application is to give the user the option of manually tilting the map image as is done in Google Earth. (3D effect)

any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: the two API are different . What do you mean by "Migrate" ?

Comment: any way of using my existing code combined with GE Api. All I want to do is have the 3D feature on my map, and I understand this happens only by using GE Api.

Comment: from what I have seen already, there is a way to add GE as overlay on a map using GM Api v3, but this is not my intention.

Comment: i have found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6878497/2494178 which I am now trying to add to my application and see if it works..

Comment: Please see this answer too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389109/can-you-change-the-view-in-google-earth-api-from-earth-to-map-like-in-google/19400501#19400501